# How to remove null dictionary values from json file using python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a huge dataset
I just wanted to remove these null things from my dataset
Please do help me out

```
[
    {
        "Disease": "Impetigo",
        "Symptoms": [
            " skin_rash",
            " high_fever",
            " blister",
            " red_sore_around_nose",
            " yellow_crust_ooze",
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        ]
    }
]
```

The output should be:

```
[
    {
        "Disease": "Impetigo",
        "Symptoms": [
            " skin_rash",
            " high_fever",
            " blister",
            " red_sore_around_nose",
            " yellow_crust_ooze",
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Wondering if `json.dumps`, a regex or filter for `s/^\s*null,\s*$//g`, and a `json.loads` would do this generally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` to remove `null` entries:

```py
import json

with open('input.json') as input_file, open('output.json', 'w') as output_file:
    data = json.load(input_file)

    for disease in data:
        disease['Symptoms'] = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, disease['Symptoms']))

    json.dump(data, output_file, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) for this. Starting from the JSON you have and converting it into a dictionary, it would look something like this:

```
import json

data_json = '[ { "Disease": "Impetigo", "Symptoms": [ " skin_rash", " high_fever", " blister", " red_sore_around_nose", " yellow_crust_ooze", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] } ]'
data_dict = json.loads(data_json)

# Now cleanup the key in each record
for record in data_dict:
    item['Symptoms'] = [x for x in item['Symptoms'] if x is not None]
```